# How to update the model in the dynamically generated view?

Tags: elm

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (disabled)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init =
            { count = 0
            , node = text ""
            , inactive = False
            }
        , update = update
        , view = view
        }


type Msg
    = Increment
    | AddNode


update msg model =
    case msg of
        Increment ->
            Debug.log "count"
                { model
                    | count = model.count + 1
                }

        AddNode ->
            let
                viewDynamic =
                    div []
                        [ text (String.fromInt model.count) ]
            in
            { model
                | node =
                    div []
                        [ button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
                        , viewDynamic
                        ]
                , inactive = True
            }


view model =
    let
        viewStatic =
            button
                [ disabled model.inactive
                , onClick AddNode
                ]
                [ text "new" ]
    in
    div []
        [ viewStatic
        , model.node
        ]
```

Above, the initial static view can react to the update of `model.inactive`, but the subsequent dynamic view fails to update `model.count`.  How to ideally achieve it?

Comment: You've forgot to include the `Model` type in the code. In any case, I don't think it's a good idea to put rendering code in the model, for exactly this reason. What is it you're trying to accomplish here, and why did you choose to try this approach rather than defining `viewDynamic` at the top level and use a custom type in the model that you can switch on in `view` to conditionally render `viewDynamic`

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ideally thanks to the hints from @glennsl .

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (disabled)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init =
            { count = 0
            , added = False
            , inactive = False
            }
        , update = update
        , view = view
        }


type Msg
    = Increment
    | AddNode


update msg model =
    case msg of
        Increment ->
            { model | count = model.count + 1 }

        AddNode ->
            { model | inactive = True, added = True }


view model =
    let
        viewStatic =
            button
                [ disabled model.inactive
                , onClick AddNode
                ]
                [ text "new" ]

        viewDynamic =
            div []
                [ text (String.fromInt model.count) ]
    in
    div []
        [ viewStatic
        , if model.added then
            div []
                [ button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
                , viewDynamic
                ]

          else
            text ""
        ]
```